# jquery data table release

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have three tabs in one page and i use jquery data table. It seems that they have effect on each other. I want when a tab is clicked, all effects of other tabs to be remove. I've tested below lines, it makes it better, but the effects aren't completely removed.

```
$( '#inbox' ).empty();
 $( '#inbox' ).html("");
```

Isn't a way to release data tables completely?
EDIT:
this is my base.html which contains 4 tabs, three of them use data table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $( document ).ready( function() {            
            $("tr td input[type='checkbox']").live('change',    function() {
                $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass('row_selected');
                updateActions();
            });            
            $( '#inbox' ).html( '{% trans "waiting ..." %}' ).load( 'inbox/');
           $( '#inbox_list' ).click( function() {
               $( '#inbox' ).html("");
               $( '#outbox' ).html("");
               $( '#compose' ).html("");
               $( '#trash' ).html("");
               $( '#inbox' ).html( '{% trans "waiting ..." %}' ).load( 'inbox/');
            });
            $( '#outbox_list' ).click( function() {
                $( '#inbox' ).html("");
                $( '#outbox' ).html("");
                $( '#compose' ).html("");
                $( '#trash' ).html("");
                $( '#outbox' ).html( '{% trans "waiting ..." %}' ).load( 'outbox/');
            });
            $( '#compose_list' ).click( function() {
                $( '#inbox' ).html("");
                $( '#outbox' ).html("");
                $( '#compose' ).empty();
                $( '#trash' ).html("");
                $( '#compose' ).html( '{% trans "waiting ..." %}' ).load( 'compose/');
            });
            $( '#trash_list' ).click( function() {
                $( '#inbox' ).html("");
                $( '#outbox' ).html("");
                $( '#compose' ).html("");
                $( '#trash' ).html("");
                $( '#trash' ).html( '{% trans "waiting ..." %}' ).load( 'trash1/');
            });
        });
</script>

<ul class="tabber">
        <li><a id="inbox_list" href="#inbox">{% trans "inbox" %}</a> </li>
        <li><a id="outbox_list" href="#outbox">{% trans "sent" %}</a> </li>
        <li><a id="compose_list" href="#compose">{%  trans "compose" %}</a> </li>
        <li><a id="trash_list" href="#trash">{%  trans "trash" %}</a> </li>
</ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="inbox" class="tabContent">
                loading...
            </div>
            <div id="outbox" class="tabContent">
                loading...
            </div>
            <div id="compose" class="tabContent">
                loading...
            </div>
            <div id="trash" class="tabContent">
                loading...
            </div>
```

and i have this script in my three tabs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // =======================================================================
        // DataTables and action buttons
        // =======================================================================
        var oTable;
        var action = 'class="action fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-state-disabled ui-corner-all"';
        var addActionButton = function (action) {
            $('#DataTables_Table_0_length').before(action);
        };
        var updateActions = function () {
            if ($('tr.row_selected').length > 0) {
                $('.action:not(.always)').removeClass('ui-state-disabled')
            }
            else {
                $('.action:not(.always)').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            }
        };
        var selectNone = function () {
            $('input#select-box').prop('checked', false);
            $('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).change();
        };
        var selectAll = function () {
            $('input#select-box').prop('checked', true);
            $('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').prop('checked', true).change();
        };
        $(function() {
            oTable = $("table.messages").dataTable({
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": 0, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                    { "sWidth": "160px", "aTargets": [ 3,1 ] }
                ],
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "trash/",
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": '<"#filter"f><"clear"><"H"lr><"#htool">t<"F"ip>',
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sZeroRecords": '{% trans "No messages match your filter" %}',
                    "sProcessing": '{% trans "Processing" %}',
                    "sSearch": '{% trans "Search" %}',
                    "sInfo": '{% trans "Displaying _START_ to _END_ from _TOTAL_ messages" %}',
                    "sInfoFiltered": '{% trans " - filtered from _MAX_ messages" %}',
                    "sInfoEmpty": '{% trans "Nothing to desplay" %}',
                    "sLoadingRecords": '{% trans "Loading records" %}',
                    "sLengthMenu": '{% trans "Display _MENU_ messages" %}',
                    "sEmptyTable": '{% trans "Nothing to desplay" %}',
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": '{% trans "First" %}',
                        "sLast": '{% trans "Last" %}',
                        "sPrevious": '{% trans "Previous" %}',
                        "sNext": '{% trans "Next" %}'
                    }
                }
            });

            $("tr td input[type='checkbox']").live('change',    function() {
                $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass('row_selected');
                updateActions();
            });

            addActionButton('<input type="checkbox" id="select-box">');
            $('input#select-box').change(function() {
                if($('input#select-box:checked').length > 0){
                    selectAll();
                }
                else {
                    selectNone();
                }
            });

            addActionButton('<a href="#" id="refresh" class="always action fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all">{% trans "refresh " %}</a>');
            $('a#refresh').click(function() {
                selectNone();
                updateActions();
                oTable.fnDraw();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script> 

<table class="messages">
    <thead>
        <tr><th></th><th>{% trans "Sender" %}</th><th>{% trans "Subject" %}</th><th>{% trans "Date" %}</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table></div>
```

Comment: Use `fnDestroy` method. http://datatables.net/api

Comment: Please post some more code: page, tabs and datatables structure, javascript tables initialization.

Comment: you can run multiple instances of datatables and they **should NOT** affect each other. It sounds like something is wrong in your implementation code. Show some more code. Is it possible you are repeating ID's in the page?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your 3 tables the same class

```
<table class="data_tables" ...>
```

..

And jquery:

```
 $('.data_tables').html("");
```

or

```
$('.data_tables').hide();
```

or (if you want effect)

```
$('.data_tables').fadeOut(1000); // 1000 is the millisecond, 1000 = 1 second, you can change it.
```

**another solution** is to make div that wrap the 3 tables, and then use: `html("")` or `hide()` or `fadeOut(number)`..